# Peak heap size - what is meant?

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection, jvm, monitoring

I found this interesting article which describes some micrometrics to forecast application performance (link: https://blog.gceasy.io/2019/03/13/micrometrics-to-forecast-application-performance/).

Under **#4. PEAK HEAP SIZE** it is stated:

> Peak heap size is the maximum amount of memory consumed by your application. If peak heap size goes beyond a limit you must investigate it. Maybe there is a potential memory leak in the application, newly introduced code (or 3rd libraries/frameworks) is consuming lot of memory.

I am now wondering what is exactly meant by peak heap size. If the applications are monitored using JVM Micrometer dashboard (link: https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/4701), there is a section JVM Memory.
It is split in:

- JVM Heap
- JVM Non-Heap
- JVM Total

Each of this graphs is split into max, commited and used. Now, I am stumbling, which of this graphs shows me Peak heap size. Following the definition I would say it is the metric **JVM Total - max**. Where I am stumbling is the term Peak **Heap** size. And in JVM Total also Non-Heap Memory is included. But the definition above says the "maximum amount of memory consumed by your application" is peak heap size, so I guess it is JVM Total or is it JVM Heap?

Could someone clarify this?

NOTE: Using JVM Micrometer dashboard I also get JVM Memory Pools (Heap) which is split into Eden Space, Survivor Space and Tenured Gen. I do not think, I have to look here for Peak Heap size, should I?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: “peak” means “peak”, literally, like in “mountain peak”. So it’s not a curve at all. Besides that, I strongly disagree with the quoted text. If you experience a high peak instead of a steadily high curve, it’s a sign that everything is fine.

Comment: Okay, thanks! So, it is the maximum amount. But is it the maximum amount of JVM Total or JVM Heap or another metric? I would also agree that one high peak is not a problem but constant high values could be one..

Comment: That cited text seems to refer to the “used size” of the heap memory. In principle, the JMX facility supports to remember the peek value of a lot of numeric values until the monitoring tool resets it. It’s up to the tool to decide which to request and display.

Comment: Ok, thank you! That seems to be plausible.